# How do I plot data with time?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I have a `csv` where I have recorded my calorie intake throughout the day for 7 days.

There are two columns in the csv: 
*time of day* and *amount of calories*

I need to load this data and plot it in a graph. I'm trying to do a line plot where I compare the 7 days to each other on the same graph.

The x ticks range from 0-24 (representing each hour of the day), but I don't know how to plot each recording accordingly to the x ticks. I'm not sure I'm making sense. What I mean is that if I have a recording at 21:30, it should plot between the x ticks, 21 and 22, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. Do you know how to line plot, but not sure how to handle x axis? or you don't know how to plot a line graph at all?

Comment: Not sure how to handle the x-axis. The x ticks range from 0-24, but I don't have 24 recordings of each day.

Comment: Post a sample of the data as text please.  Do not paste it as a screen shot.  All columns and 10ish rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really sure what you expected from x-axis to be. Let's take the following example:

```py
import pandas
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pandas.DataFrame({"Time":["07:10", "09:30", "21:30"], "Value": [1000, 1200, 1400]})
plt.plot(df["Time"], df["Value"] ,'ro')
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

As you can see, it will automatically will plot the x-values (time of day). If you want to be precisely 0-24 with 1 hour jump, I recommend to first convert values to `datetime` or `time` objects and work with them, as it easier that way.

Comment: If I misunderstood your intention on the desired output (or you need help to conversion) please let me know, I'll be happy to edit my post to correctly answer your question

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about datetime and time objects.